# Flutter returning null while trying to acquire data from php backend

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

Here is my frontend code. I's sincerely frustrated about what could be going on here.

I want to collect data to a flutter app from a serverside php code..

The function responsible for this connection is in the Future _getPosts() function in the MyScaffold class.

```
class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ENPOWER DISCUSSION"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("GENERAL FEEDS"),
              onTap:(){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); //
              }
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("ENROLLMENT"),
              onTap:(){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close Navigator
                //Call a new function here

                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EnrollmentPage()),
                );                
              }              

            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("PAYMENT"),
              onTap:(){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close Navigator
                //Call a new function here

                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaymentPage()),
                );                
              }
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("FAQ"),
              onTap:(){
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close Navigator
                //Call a new function here
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FaqPage()),
                );
              }
            ),                                    
          ],
        ),
      ), 
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getPosts(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            print(snapshot.data);
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(
                child: Center(child: Text("Processing..."),),
              );
            }else{
              return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].postTitle),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),       
      );

  }

  Future<List<Post>> _getPosts() async{
    var data = await http.get("www.empowermentopportunities.com/xxyyzz/admin_panel/backend/api_connector.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Post> posts = [];

    for(var p in jsonData){
      Post post = Post(p["post_id"], p["post_title"], p["post_content"], p["post_image_url"], p["post_date"]);
      posts.add(post);
    }

    print(posts.length);
    return posts;
  }

}


class Post{
  final int postId;
  final String postTitle;
  final String postContent;
  final String postImageurl;
  final String postDate;

  Post(this.postId, this.postTitle, this.postContent, this.postImageurl, this.postDate);
}
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'My app',
    home: MyScaffold(),
  ));
}
```

This is the server side php code whose role is to collect the data from the database and then compress it to JSON before sending it to the front end caller.

```
function fetch_gen_data($offset, $total){
    include "../db/connection.php";
    $data = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $total OFFSET $offset")or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $data[] = $row;



            }


    }
    return json_encode(json_encode($data));
}
```

I then invoke that function from another one

```
echo fetch_gen_data(0, 10);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: The link to your site doesn't really help anyone here except, as this code likely has severe SQL injection bugs, someone looking to crack it. Leave those out unless they're strictly relevant to the question. Keep your question self-contained, don't depend on people clicking links to things that may or may not be online/offline/fixed/broken or what have you.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the double json encoding in the backend. If you see the response is a string and not a json.

Just go to http://www.empowermentopportunities.com/xxyyzz/admin_panel/backend/api_connector.php via browser and you'll see.

The return should be `return json_encode($data);`